How to display a very long image in plotOutput with a scroll bar?
I know that I can set a fixed width or height using the width parameter in the plotOutput() function. However, in my Shiny application, the length of the image changes based on user input, so I don't want to use a fixed width.
I've searched for related questions but couldn't find a solution to my problem. Below is a reproducible example. As you can see, due to the image being too long, part of the image is not displayed in the Shiny interface. Is there any way to add a scrollbar so that users can scroll to view the remaining part of the image?
library(shiny)
library(forestploter)
library(bslib)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Forest Plot"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("Forest Plot Example")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("forestPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$forestPlot <- renderPlot({
    
    # Load example data 
    dt <- read.csv(system.file("extdata", "example_data.csv", package = "forestploter"))
    dt <- dt[1:6,1:6]
    dt$` ` <- paste(rep(" ", 20), collapse = " ")
    
    dt$Subgroup1 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup2 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup3 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup4 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup5 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup6 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup7 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup8 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup9 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup10 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup11 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup12 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup13 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup14 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup15 <- dt$Subgroup
    dt$Subgroup16 <- dt$Subgroup
    
    # names(dt)
    
    # a long long plot
    forest(dt[,c(1:3,8:23, 7)],
           est = dt$est,
           lower = dt$low,
           upper = dt$hi,
           ci_column = 20)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)




This question is similar to: Using scroll bars for big plots in R Shiny app. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
